# iOS App, Objective-C: Weird Podfile

Tags: ios, cocoapods, podfile

I am trying to get a app running which was written by some guys some years ago. Instead of a Podfile, the app had a file called SBPodfile with the following content:

```
#platform :ios, "8.0"
#use_frameworks!

target '------' do

pod 'ZCSFileExtensionForMimeType', :git => 'https://github.com/----/ZCSFileExtensionForMimeType.git'
pod 'AMSlideMenu', '~> 1.5.4'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'SVProgressHUD', '~> 1.1'

SB_PODS_START
ObjCSBLog
ObjCSBDeviceHelper
ObjCSBSynthesizeSingleton
ObjCSBFileHandler
ObjCSBImageCreationHelper
ObjCSBAlertViewHelper
SB_PODS_END

end

target 'actionExtension' do

pod 'ZCSFileExtensionForMimeType', :git => 'https://github.com/-----/ZCSFileExtensionForMimeType.git'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'UAProgressView', '~> 0.1'

SB_PODS_START
ObjCSBLog
ObjCSBDeviceHelper
ObjCSBSynthesizeSingleton
ObjCSBFileHandler
SB_PODS_END

end

target '-----' do

end
```

The app wouldn't compile because there was no Podfile. So I renamed the SBPodfile to Podfile. Now I am getting the error that the constant "SB_PODS_START" is not defined. I couldn't find out anything about that weird "SB block" on google. Does anyone have a clue what it is.
I have to add that I am relatively new to iOS development, especially in objective c.

Edit: I think that SB stands for the Company which developed the App and they are loading some custom libraries. But I still don't know how it works.